# html text field with multiple columns

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am designing an html form and I have to design a text field with multiple columns   as below image,

[image]

Have an alternate solution like the below snippet but it's too long, I want solution in one line like other html elements are providing

```
<input type="text" maxlength="1" style="width:20px;"><input type="text" maxlength="1" style="width:20px;>"<input type="text" maxlength="1" style="width:20px;"><input type="text" maxlength="1" style="width:20px;"><input type="text" maxlength="1" style="width:20px;"><input type="text" maxlength="1" style="width:20px;"><input type="text" maxlength="1" style="width:20px;">
```

Answer (score -1):

what you want is a component. So you should consider using a framework like vue.js, react.js or webcomponents.

EDIT:

Okay try something like this with jquery. I f you also dont want to use jquery its a bit more complicated but the idea remains the same:

```
let $b = $("<form>");

for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    let $n = $("<input type='text'>");
    $n.attr("name","inp"+i);
    $n.attr("id","inp"+i);
    $b.append($n);
}

$("#someplaceinyourapp").append($b)
```

Comment: this requirement is just for one page so I don't want to use any framework. I am looking this solution in only using html and javascript.